# User Profile permalink to subdomain Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, subdomain, permalinks

Is it possible to map user profile pages to sub-domains in WordPress? I have a link in bio site and the urls are currently in the form [www.example.com/templatepage/user_nicename](http://www.example.com/templatepage/user_nicename)

However, I want the URL to look like sampleuser.example.com . Is there anyway of achieving this? The users are creating their own profiles by the way on signup and I want it to do this mapping automatically if possible.

Users are allowed to edit this link in the front end by using user_nicename alternative.

I've gotten this far by using JetEngine's Profile Builder, but the profile links currently display as [www.mysite.com/templatepage/user_nicename](http://www.mysite.com/templatepage/user_nicename)

I would like to shorten the profile permalinks to be in form of [www.user_nicename.mysite.com](http://www.user_nicename.mysite.com) or [www.mysite.com/user_nicename](http://www.mysite.com/user_nicename)